# Can we create specflow Table instance at runtime and add values in it?

Tags: specflow, allure

I am creating automation solution where I will connect to JIRA to get details like No of test cases, pass / fail count etc & generate a report to show these details.

SO I thought, I will specFlow to increase readability and allure reports to generate my reports. Hence, I am trying to create Specflow Table instance runtime and attach to report. Since, I am not passing any data to step, specflow table instance is not created.

Eg:

```
Given I am connected to Jira   
And I get test cases details
```

```
[Given(@"T get test cases details")]
public void GivenGetTestDetails()
   {
       // Add data from Jira to Table
   }
```

And Generate report that has data like

[image: Check dummy report here]

Is there a way to create Table instance at runtime and add values in it then attach to allure report?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing things backwards. Instead of Jira driving the test cases, SpecFlow should be driving the test results recorded in Jira. I'm just not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are these Jira test cases used for manual testing? Jira should have reports for test runs and results.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use an API to build the Allure report directly?

Comment: @GregBurghardt This is for compliance Engine project, where I have to verify if projects are following standards of JIRA defined by compliance team.

Comment: @GregBurghardt How do I use API to build the allure report?

Comment: I have no idea. You'll have to play around with it.